# 32bit and 64bit Versions of PostgreSQL 9.1 ODBC are Mixed Up

Tags: postgresql, 64-bit, odbc, sas

I've installed both the 32bit and 64bit versions of psqlODBC 9.1.  When I configure both a 32bit and a 64bit System DSN they get written to the ODBC.ini file incorrectly:

> ```
> [ODBC 32 bit Data Sources]
> pg_crdb_latest=PostgreSQL Unicode (32 bit)
> pg_crdb_latest_32=PostgreSQL Unicode(x64) (32 bit)
> [pg_crdb_latest]
> Driver32=C:\Program Files (x86)\psqlODBC\0901\bin\psqlodbc35w.dll
> [pg_crdb_latest_32]
> Driver32=C:\Program Files\psqlODBC\0901\bin\psqlodbc35w.dll
> ```

The **pg_crdb_latest** DSN was added using the **64bit ODBC Data Source Administrator**.  The **pg_crdb_latest_32** DSN was added with the **32bit** one.

FYI - I installed the 32bit version first, then the 64bit version.

The outcome is I get this error when trying to connect to PostgreSQL 9.1 64bit in SAS 9.2 64bit:

> ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch
>   between the Driver and Application

Any ideas how to set this right?  I'm running Windows 7 Pro 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link explains it all

http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/64-bit.html#odbc-windows

So two things:

1. Windows has very poor file and directory naming conventions regarding ODBC - hence the confusion
2. 64bit PostgreSQL ODBC is currently very slow (10x slower than SAS to SQL 64bit via OLEDB) - I'll investigate this further